# How to describe this sitting position

Tags: sentence-construction

Seat on your hip and pair your feet with no space with no space between edges of your feet.
Seat on your hip and connect your feet with no space between edges of your feet.

Like this picture. 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/1zonie/4464732309/

Comment: An easy way to describe this would be: _Sit down [on the floor], put your feet together, and pull your knees to your chest_. (Incidentally, as an experiment, I just gave those exact instructions to my daughter, to see what she would do. Immediately, she sat in exactly the same position as the girl in the picture – even the hands.)

Comment: 'Pull your knees to your chest' works; or something else specifiying that the position is 'with your knees together'. Otherwise your instructions would be satisfied by putting the soles of feet together, dropping the knees wide to the sides - which is how I first read your instructions when you say 'no space between edges of your feet'. This is more complex than simply 'with your feet together' so I thought it had to be a bit more unusual.

Answer (score 2):

This pose is frequently described as "hugging your knees to your chest."

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you repeat (almost) your whole sentence twice, and the first time around you repeat *with no space*. That seems confusing.

Then, as far as the positioning of the feet is concerned, that is pretty clear. Both *pair* and *connect* are conveying the right meaning, although you could also simply use *place*.

The simplest option would be

> Place your feet together so there is no space between them.

Now, for the confusing part: I was really wondering what you meant with sit on your hip.

After looking at the picture, I can assure you that the part of her body that she is sitting on is not her hip.

There are many words for that part, but among the politer ones are *behind* or *buttocks*.

However, you do not need to name that, as she is sitting on what anyone would sit at if no further directions are given.

So this would describe the whole pose:

> Sit down with your feet together (so there is no space between them).

Comment: Fortunately, given that the person is sitting where a person usually sits, there's no need to specify which part she's sitting on. She's simply _sitting_.

Comment: Good point, I edited :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest,

> (She is) sitting, hugging (her) knees.

With a small risk of being a little ambiguous (some might cross their legs, which in that case you might need to add "feet together"), I'd say that it is clear and concise enough.